# How to assign list as observation in data table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data table that contains character observations:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

DT = data.table(strings = c('AAABD', 'BBDA', 'AACBDAA', 'ABACD'))
```

I would like to create a variable that contains counts of 'A', 'AA', and 'AAA' in each observation as a list. To do this I have created a function foo:

```
foo <- function(str) {
    n <- str_count(str, 'A')
    n2 <- str_count(str, 'AA')
    n3 <- str_count(str, 'AAA')
    df <- list('n' = n, 'n2' = n2, 'n3' = n3)

    return(df)
}
```

I apply this function to DT to create a new variable for count observation as a list:

```
DT[, count := foo(strings)]
```

When I do this, I receive this error:

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(counts, foo(strings))) :
  Supplied 3 items to be assigned to 4 items of column 'counts' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
```

The data table returned has count variable lists of size 4 instead of size 3 and does not represent the amount of 'A', 'AA', and 'AAA' accurately for each string observation in variable `strings`. How can I assign a list as an observation in a data table?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. However, it is unclear to me how you want you output? Can you provide or describe your wanted output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `transpose` the `list`:

```
foo <- function(str) {
  n <- str_count(str, 'A')
  n2 <- str_count(str, 'AA')
  n3 <- str_count(str, 'AAA')
  df <- transpose(list('n' = n, 'n2' = n2, 'n3' = n3)) # <- add transpose 
  return(df)
}

DT[, count := foo(strings)]
DT
#     strings count
#  1:   AAABD 3,1,1
#  2:    BBDA 1,0,0
#  3: AACBDAA 4,2,0
#  4:   ABACD 2,0,0

str(DT)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ strings: chr  "AAABD" "BBDA" "AACBDAA" "ABACD"
# $ count  :List of 4
#  ..$ : int  3 1 1
#  ..$ : int  1 0 0
#  ..$ : int  4 2 0
#  ..$ : int  2 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I was looking for! As a follow up question, is it possible to subset an item of the list from the data table to use in ggplot? Thank you.

Comment: I would like to be able to plot the first item (or second or third) of the list in `count` against another variable in my data set. In the data set I am working with, it is useful to have `count` as a list for simplicity of statistical analysis but also because  it makes the data set less wieldy and easier to peruse for data exploration (I have over 100 variables in my data set). Having it as a list, however, has posed a new challenge in subsetting specific items in the list to use as a variable to plot against.

Comment: For plotting (_especially_ with `ggplot`) I think you should avoid list columns and rather keep your data tidy (tidier), with one observation per row. That said, to extract the values of a certain row, e.g. 3, as a vector: `DT[ , count[[3]]]` or `unlist(DT[3]$count)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your answer was able to help me determine the solution I was looking for:

`ggplot(data = DT, aes(x = unlist(lapply(count, '[', 1)), y = unlist(lapply(count, '[', 2)))) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a list of columns to a single name can result in the warning message.  Instead it can be

```
DT[, c('n', 'n2', 'n3') := .(str_count(strings, 'A'), 
        str_count(strings, 'AA'),  str_count(strings, 'AAA'))]
```

Comment: Surely there is an existing Q&A for this? (I searched but couldn't find one)